# ListView addView(View child, int index) not working

Tags: android, listview

I'm trying to add a custom view to my listview (which is already populated) using this code:

```
listview.addView(customView,rowNumber);
```

but my app crashes..

I realized that if I use this code :

```
    list.addFooterView(customView);
```

it works, but I can't choose where to place the view . What can I do?

Comment: Put the stacktarce in the question, it's more easy to understand your problem

Comment: i dont think you can insert a view randomly inside a listView.

Comment: What is the customView? Is it a compound view? Is it an inflated view? Any stacktrace please?

Comment: you can add header and footer, how can you add one different layout row view inside listview?

Comment: customView is an inflated view

Answer (score 1):

The `addFooterView` works because it adds on the bottom. You can't add anything in the `Listview` just putting it using `addView`. Instead, do the following example:

After doing it:

```
ArrayList<Object> _views = new ArrayList<Object>();
_views.add(new View());
_views.add(new View2());

ArrayAdapter<Object> _adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Object>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, _views)

mListView.setAdapter(_adapter);
```

You only need to add the new `View` into `ArrayList` and notify the adapter that the listview had changed such as:

```
_views.add(new View3());

_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: not working, my view shows in the listview as a text view with that text :"android.widget.LinearLayout{3eb2........}.....0,0-0,0}"

Comment: As I said my code is just an example. You must adapt it to what you need. Anyway, you can show part of your code so that I could explain it with your own code, if you want.